# framework for creating local environment for native libraries

Tags: python, linux, macos, environment, homebrew

I write code that often depends on native libraries on linux or mac os. Usually I don't have permissions to install the respective native lib in the system, so I resort to creating a local folder ~/env where I install my libs. I than add this to my PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, C_INCLUDE_DIRS, etc. 
I really like **homebrew** and I was wondering if there is a framework (or a tool) like that (hopefully in python :) ) that will ease the process of adding native dependencies to my local environemt on both linux and mac. Thanks!

Cheers

Comment: `chroot` may be overkill but you could try that.

Comment: This won't help install your libs, but is very useful for managing their dependencies. See [Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for pointing out the Modules project, I'll definitely check it out

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried virtualenv [1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)?

It's dead easy to create your own environment, then switch into it and install whatever you need with easy_install or pypi

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! I use virtualenv for all the python specific modules I need, however say I need to install libev for fapws3, virtualenv won't help me there - I'd have to install it either in the system path or in a separate path and add that path to my environment just like the homebrew package manager does. I have some scripts that "do" this - I was just wondering if there is a more sustainable way of doing it. I really like the idea of defining "recipes" for your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

GNU autoconf, automake, libtool will do the job nicely and in a very clean and portable manner... but you'll need a good amount of time and work to make it working correctly.

You may also be interested in using WAF: http://code.google.com/p/waf/

Comment: This is what I already do :), I have some scripts that help, but they are just messy and hard to maintain. I was wondering if there is a more sustainable way. Thanks